# Задержка между вызовом инициализации формы и самой инициализацией

Tags: c#, отладка

Имеется код `AddSupply supply = new AddSupply(user, connectionString);`

Событие Load отсутствует. Перед отображением формы существует задержка. В чем проблема?

Достиг первой точки останова.
[image: Первая точка останова]

Достиг второй точки останова через 10 сек.
[image: Вторая точка останова]

Comment: Попробуйте то же измерение без отладчика. Возможно, замедление именно в нём.

Comment: @VladD Без отладчика перед отображением формы проходит примерно 5 секунд

Comment: Ну это перед отображением формы, это совсем другой вопрос. А сколько проходит между двумя строками, в которых у вас точки останова? Измерьте.

Comment: А в медленном отображении формы, думаю, виноват другой код. Например, код, читающий из базы данных.

Comment: У вас по сути смешаны два вопроса. Первый, 10 секунд на вызов метода. Тут скорее всего виноват отладчик, хотя может быть и инициализация полей, которую вы не показываете. Второй, медленное отображение UI. Тут однозначно вы сами делаете что-то медленное в UI-потоке, чудес не бывает.

Comment: @VladD Инициализация происходит за 3 секунды, выборка из БД происходит в другом потоке, использую BackgroundWorker, использовал StopWatch для замера

Comment: То есть расстояние от вызова конструктора до InitializeComponent() 3 секунды? Ого. Покажите весь класс тогда. В коде, который вы привели, проблемы нет. Возможно, виновата инициализация полей.

Comment: @VladD После пересоздания обеих форм без наследования от MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm, проблема исчезла, спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Ах вот оно что! Ну вы б хоть написали тогда ответ.

Comment: @VladD извините, был слишком рад xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело было в фреймворке MetroFraemwork, без его использования все работает отлично